# How to send notification on data changes in databases

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to send notification to user on data changes in database using firebase ?
I am newbie and searched everywhere no such help.. please help me.
I got to know that it's possible using firebase cloud function but I did not got any example code to understand it. So please help by giving any example code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [first use-case mentioned in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) and the [sample code for that use-case](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications). They quite literally describe what you're asking for.

Note that this code is non-trivial, since the entire use-case is quite involved. You will have to make sure you understand all parts well, before you try to make any changes to the sample code. To get this understanding, you might be better served by following the more basic documentation for the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) and [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), and the codelab for [iOS](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/), [Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/), and/or [Web](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/).